# HTML 5 section division

Tags: html

This is my website code in HTML 5 In this code we make some sections as u see header banner and nav As I dont understand why we write Header Banner And Nav separately while in same Code And whats the main reason behind making these sections? And I dont understand That Banner Code Why we Use Banner Code?

```
    <!-- Header -->
            <header id="header">
                <div class="logo container">
                    <div>
                        <h1><a href="index.html" id="logo">Malik Waqar Azim</a></h1>
                        <br><br>
                        <p>Bachelors in Software Engineering</p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>

        <!-- Nav -->
            <nav id="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="current"><a href="about-me.html">About Me</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact-me.html">Contact Me</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

        <!-- Banner -->
            <div id="banner-wrapper">
                <section id="banner">
                    <h2>About Me</h2>
                    <p>I am currently pursuing bachelors in software engineering at UET Taxila.</p>
                    <p>I completed my intermediate and matriculation from Fauji Foundation College Lalazar</p>

                </section>
            </div>
```

Comment: You're talking about `<!-- ... -->`? These are just HTML comments and don't necessarily mean anything. If that's not what you're asking, your question is pretty unclear...

Comment: I am new in programming field And I started Programming two weeks Ago But Thanks for your help I got my Answer in your Comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different sections in html5 language are like boxes for some content. HTML5 language make structure of document of your webpage. Every web browser has their own standard CSS style. If you didn't link custom style, it use this one to know how to show the html elements. 
This banner is div - box in which there are informations about you. In this example you have id of div. The 'id' attribute is neccessery if you want to set some styles for this particular box.